# time complexity for N remove operations from the front of a Java.util.LinkedList of length N

Tags: java, complexity-theory

As per the question over, the Remove from the first item of a linked list is 0(1), but if its "n remove operations," will it be o(1) or o(n)?

Comment: If you do n O(1) operations, that's going to be O(n).

Comment: so for the statement "N remove operations from the front of a Java.util.LinkedList of length N" the answer is O(n)?